# Добавление кода в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Я весьма слаб в кодинге. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и как добавить к шаблону ВП сверху в `<header>` дополнительную полоску с нужным мне цветом? И как добавить туда, чтобы слева социальные ссылки были значками, а справа - поля "задать вопрос" и "обратная связь"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я боюсь, что при такой постановке вопроса Вы не получите адекватного ответа. Всё зависит от шаблона и от Вашего уровня понимания PHP/HTML, а также от конкретного требования. В некоторых темах на Wordpress доступны настройки (в админке слева, найдите там "внешний вид") и там с помощью изменения настроек темы или добавления новых виджетов в боковую панель обычно можно добиться желаемых изменений. В противном случае последний пункт меню ("редактор") в пункте "внешний вид", позволяет залезть прямо в код шаблона и все там поменять по своему усмотрению. Но тут, повторюсь, всё зависит от вашего понимания языка, на котором всё написано, а также от понимания API самого WP. Более точного ответа при таком вопросе я даже не представляю.

Comment: Скажем так. Я более менее разбираюсь. Мне нужно понимание как впихнуть полоску шириной N-пикслей и M-цвета в редакторе (какой код и перед чем вставить его?). Я так понимаю все это запихивается в style.css.

Comment: Нет, полоску можно сделать кучей способов, не обязательно в CSS (хотя вариант наилучший). Нужно в редакторе темы найти место, которое отвечает за вывод той области страницы, где Вы хотите полоску. Вставить туда какой-нибудь объект (например, div) и сделать его нужного размера и цвета (например, через CSS). Или Вам нужен конкретно код такого div?

Comment: Именно :) Нужен сам код div. Хотя очень интересно узнать каким еще функционалом это можно сделать.

Comment: В таком случае, Вам было проще погуглить. Я вот за 7 секунд нашёл [вариант с HR](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-sdelat-tsvetnuyu-gorizontalnuyu-liniyu)

Comment: Но это же все html? Для css это не подойдет =(

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я не понимаю, как именно Вы хотите что-то отобразить. Вы можете скопировать из примера блок между тэгами <style></style> в CSS. Но если Вам нужна полоска, то придётся всё равно что-то прописать в html-файле. CSS - это файл стиля, он задаёт стиль, а не объект. Если Вы не понимаете, о чём я говорю, то лучше наймите человека, который просто сделает работу за вас, либо прочитайте учебник по данной теме. Тут же у нас не клуб любителей делать что-то за других. Не видя вашего кода, я ничего не могу больше сказать.

Comment: Давайте так :) Цветной блок нужен. Длинной 976px, шириной 36px, с цветом: #867550 в html.

Comment: Очень просто:  `<hr style="width: 976px; height: 36px; background-color: #867550; border: 0px;" />`

Comment: Слушайте. Спасибо вам огромное. Стало стыдно, прочитал про <div>. С ним и сделал. Тем более туда в нутро можно накидать то что мне нужно.

Comment: Да не за что, просто в следующий раз СРАЗУ чётко пишите, что конкретно нужно, иначе так и будем кота за хвост тянуть.